# WhenEvent method with 3 conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve system of differential equations below

$$x''(t)=-2.25cos(1.5t)-x(t)-x'(t)$$

$$y''(t)=-1.125cos(1.5t)-4y(t)-y'(t)$$

$$z'(t)=\begin{cases}x(t)-(1+y(t)), & \text{if } x>(1+y) \\
\\
0, & \text{if } |x|<(1+y) \\
\\
x(t)+(1+y(t)), & \text{if } x<-(1+y)
\end{cases}
$$

I can solve the equations for $x$ and $y$, but I have no idea how to implement WhenEvent Method to solve for $z$. Notice that there are 3 conditions for $z$.

EDIT 11/14:

I tried code below

```
sol1 = First@NDSolve[{x''[t] == -2.25 Cos[1.5 t] - x[t] - x'[t],
 x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 30}]
sol2 = First@NDSolve[{y''[t] == -1.125 Cos[1.5 t] - 4 y[t] - y'[t],
 y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 30}]

sol3 = NDSolve[z'[t] == a[t], z[0] = 0,
 WhenEvent[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol1] > 1 + Evaluate[y[t] /. sol2],
  a[t] -> Evaluate[x[t] /. sol1 - (1 + Evaluate[y[t] /. sol2])]],
 WhenEvent[Abs[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol1]] < 1 + Evaluate[y[t] /. sol2],
  a[t] -> 0],
 WhenEvent[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol1] < -(1 + Evaluate[y[t] /. sol2]),
  a[t] -> Evaluate[x[t] /. sol1] + (1 + Evaluate[y[t] /. sol2])], 
z, {t, 0, 30}]

Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol1], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol2], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[z[t] /. sol3], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

But it returns many errors I don't understand.
What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html) function in the definition of DE. So for system at hand the `NDSolve` command would be

```
xyz = First@
  NDSolve[{x''[t] == -2.25 Cos[1.5 t] - x[t] - x'[t], x[0] == 0, 
    x'[0] == 0, y''[t] == -1.125 Cos[1.5 t] - 4 y[t] - y'[t], 
    y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, 
    z'[t] == 
     Piecewise[{{x[t] - (1 + y[t]), x[t] > 1 + y[t]}, {0, 
        Abs[x[t]] <= 1 + y[t]}, {x[t] + (1 + y[t]), 
        x[t] < -1 - y[t]}}], z[0] == 0}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 30}];
```

Then the plot of the solution is

```
Plot[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. xyz // Evaluate, {t, 0, 30}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x(t)", "y(t)", "z(t)"}, AxesLabel -> {"t", None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Thank you mmal! I didn't know you can use piecewise inside NDSolve! And also, if I may ask, what is the function of "First@" before NDSolve? I often see that, but couldn't find the tutorial.

Comment: You're welcome. I have used `First` since `NDSolve` returns list of solutions (in general there may be more than one solution), I'm taking first element of that list (which in this particular case has exactly one element). Just compare output of `NDSolve[...]` with `First[NDSolve[...]]` and how to use them, etc.