# How to compute DSolve or NDSolve for kind of piece wise function?

Tags: differential-equations, webmathematica, singularity, calculus-and-analysis

I need to Compute the expression for two functions. q[t] and q1[t] over certain range of time. The code is given below.

```
Remove["Global`*"];
e = 1.6*10^-19;
h = 6.63*10^-34;
phi = 0.33*1.6*10^-19;
s = 66*10^-9;
m = 9.11*10^-31;
A = 10^-4;
pi = 3.14;
\[Epsilon]0 = 8.85*10^-12;
k1 = 7;
k2 = 7;
dt = 100*10^-9;
r = 1;
fre = 10000;
v0 = 8.7;
T = .5*(1/fre);
v[t] = (v0*Sin[2*\[Pi]*fre*t]);
ListPlot[Table[{t, %}, {t, 0, T, T/(1000 + 1)}]]

c0 = (A*\[Epsilon]0*k1)/dt;
cap = c0/(1 + (((s*q1[t])/(dt*q[t]))));

eQ = (q[t] + q1[t])/(2*A*\[Epsilon]0*k2);
vk = eQ*s;

ik1 = (e*A)/(2*\[Pi]*h*s^2) ((phi - (e*vk)/2)*E^((-((4*\[Pi]*(Sqrt[2*m])*s)/h))*(Sqrt[phi - (e*vk)/2])) - (phi + (e*vk)/2)*E^((-((4*\[Pi]*(Sqrt[2*m])*s)/h))*(Sqrt[phi + (e*vk)/2])));          (* for evk<phi*)

ik2 = (e^3*A*vk^2)/(4*\[Pi]*h*s^2) (E^(-((4*\[Pi]*(Sqrt[m])*s*phi^1.5)/(h*e*vk))) - (1 + (2*e*vk)/phi)*E^((-((4*\[Pi]*(Sqrt[m])*s*phi^1.5)/(h*e*vk)))*Sqrt[(1 + (2*e*vk)/phi)]));   (* for evk>phi*)                     

(* Below two lines are kind of Pseudocode lines to define "ik" in the dsolve expression . I am so sorry I don't know how to define this kind of if condition in mathematica and hen using in dsolve *) 
ik = If[evk < phi, ik1, ik2];

qq = First@NDSolve[{q'[t] == v[t]/r - q[t]/r*(1/cap), q1'[t] == ik, q[0] == 10^-6, q1[0] == 10^-6}, {q, q1}, t];

Rationalize@ComplexExpand[q[t] /. qq];
Plot[%, {t, 0, T}]
Rationalize@ComplexExpand[q1[t] /. qq];
Plot[%, {t, 0, T}]
```

I want to calculate the expression for q[t] and q1[t]. The initial conditions can be changed to any value within the range of 10^-12 to 0.

Edit : The Dsolve is not essential, I NDsolve can also be used.

The time range over which NDSolve is DSOLVE is computed can also be change to any range of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results can be obtained with the following changes.

First, delete the two asterisks at the end of the line `ik=ik2   (* if evk>phi*)**`, which confuse Mathematica.

Second replace `DSolve` by `First@NDSolve` (and `t` by `{ t, 0, T}` in `NDSolve`), because `DSolve` cannot solve these equations.

Third, change `T` to `.5*(1/fre)` to avoid stiffness issues.

Then, labeling the two curves for convenience,

[image]

[image]

**Corrected Addendum**

An earlier version of this addendum produced noisy results for `q1[t]`.  This can be corrected by replacing the various constants in the Question by their exact counterparts

```
e = 16*10^-20; h = 663*10^-36; phi = (1/3)*16*10^-20; s = 66*10^-9;
m = 911*10^-33; A = 10^-4; ϵ0 = 885*10^-14; k1 = 7; k2 = 7; dt = 100*10^-9;
r = 1; fre = 10000; v0 = 87/10; T = 5*(1/fre);
```

and increasing `WorkingPrecision` in `NDSolve`.

```
qq = First@NDSolve[{q'[t] == v[t]/r - q[t]/r*(1/cap), q1'[t] == ik, 
       q[0] == 10^-6, q1[0] == 10^-6}, {q, q1}, { t, 0, T}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

The condition

```
ik = Piecewise[{{Re[ik1], -phi < e*vk < phi}, {ik2, phi < e*vk}}, 0];
```

then can be introduced (based on Question [36839](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36869/whenevent-method-with-3-conditions)) to address the OP's request in the comment below.  Doing so yields for `q[t]`

[image]

and `q1[t]` is constant at `10^-6`.

The upper bound of `-phi < e*vk < phi` on `ik1` and the bound `phi < e*vk`on `ik2` in the definition of `ik` are as requested by the OP.  Since `ik1` and `ik2` are complex for `e*vk` smaller than `-2 phi`, some lower bound must be set on the use of `ik1`, and I chose to set `ik` equal to zero for `-phi < e*vk` for lack of a better choice.  In fact, the results are insensitive to the precise value of the lower bound, provided that it is not too close to `-2 phi`.  Curiously, `ik1` must be wrapped in `Abs` to avoid errors.

**Comment on the use of `Piecewise` vs `If`**

With the permission of Michael E2, I am reproducing his very use comments below.  In general, it's better to use `Piecewise` rather than `If` in constructing equations and functions for solvers (`NDSolve`, `Plot`, `NIntegrate`, etc).  The solvers have built-in routines for analyzing the discontinuities present in `Piecewise`. This should be stressed more, since it is not common in other programming languages.  The issue is that `If` uses `HoldRest` so that `ik1` and `ik2` are passed to `NDSolve` unevaluated inside the `If`. At some point `NDSolve` substitutes the initial or computed values for `q[t]`, `q1[t]` into the equations, probably with `ReplaceAll`. In that case the symbols `ik1`, `ik2` are not altered and afterwards evaluate to contain non-numeric `q[t]`, `q1[t]`; hence the `NDSolve::ndnum` error. `Piecewise` evaluates its arguments.

Comment: @bbgodfrey...Thanks for your response. I did all the three steps but still getting the same error. ik = If[evk < phi, ik1, ik2]   line is added. DSolve is replaced by First@NDSolve...T is also changed. I edited the code in my original question. Can you kindly guide me how did you get these results?

Comment: I neglected to point out that `t` must be replaced by `{ t, 0, T}` in `NDSolve`.  Also, I see that you added `ik = If[evk < phi, ik1, ik2]`, which does not work.  Use `ik = ik2` for now.

Comment: @bbgodfrey..Thanks alot . you are a life saver . Thats working fine. BUT my aim is to include the condition `ik = If[evk < phi, ik1, ik2]`...As ik is conditional not simply equal to ik2.Thanks Again

Comment: @AKKKhan In general, it's better to use `Piecewise` in constructing equations and functions for solvers (`NDSolve`, `Plot`, `NIntegrate`, etc.) and to use `If` for programming (to select blocks of code to execute).  The solvers have built-in routines for analyzing the discontinuities present in `Piecewise`.  This should be stressed more, since it is not common in other programming languages.

Comment: @MichaelE2  You are correct.  In fact, using `If` generates errors in the code here.  But, I did not know how general this issue was.  Thanks.

Comment: I did not look at closely until now, since you had solved the problem. The issue is that `If` is `HoldRest` so that `ik1` and `ik2` are passed to `NDSolve` unevaluated inside the `If`. At some point `NDSolve` substitutes the initial or computed values for `q[t]`, `q1[t]` into the equations, probably with `ReplaceAll`. In that case the symbols `ik1`, `ik2` are not altered and afterwards evaluate to contain non-numeric `q[t]`, `q1[t]`; hence the `NDSolve::ndnum` error. `Piecewise` evaluates its arguments. That's quite subtle and I had not realized it until now. Consider adding it to your answer.

Comment: I thought this seemed familiar: This difference between `If` and `Piecewise` figures in different context in [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44965/how-to-make-mathematica-simplify/79291#79291) from a month ago.